# Is it appropriate to migrate my old question to MO?

Tags: support, migration, mathoverflow

[My old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431740/23875) was still unsolved though I gave a bounty. No progression was made. Although it's not a research problem of a working mathematician, it seems that the problem is open and challenging. May I ask for a migration to MO, or I start a new question in MO?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that migration of questions older than 60 days is impossible. Before cross-posting, perhaps post this very question on meta.MO and see what sort of reaction you get. Before cross-posting a small bounty might be useful to regenerate some interest.

Comment: @AsafKaragila is correct, old questions can not be migrated, even by moderators.